# How to add a new row to a dataframe with values for certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, rows

I have a dataframe filled with data, some columns are strings and other columns contain numbers. I want to add a row at the bottom that contains averages the columns that have numbers.

My dataframe:

| Name | Sex | apples | oranges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | M | 10 | 3 |
| Mike | M | 5 | 7 |
| Anne | F | 20 | 8 |

What I want:

| Name | Sex | apples | oranges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | M | 10 | 3 |
| Mike | M | 5 | 7 |
| Anne | F | 20 | 8 |
| Averages |  | 11.6 | 6 |

I have variables  that calculated the means for the columns i need:

```
apples_mean = df['apples'].mean()
```

How can I append a new row to the bottom of my df to with the values and text I want to certain columns, while adding nothing to other columns?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'Names' is the index of the DataFrame

```
df.loc['Averages'] = df.mean(numeric_only=True)
```

Output:

```
          Sex     apples  oranges
Name                             
Jim         M  10.000000      3.0
Mike        M   5.000000      7.0
Anne        F  20.000000      8.0
Averages  NaN  11.666667      6.0
```

If you want, you can fill the NaNs resulting from non-numeric columns with empty strings.

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
         Sex     apples  oranges
Name                            
Jim        M  10.000000      3.0
Mike       M   5.000000      7.0
Anne       F  20.000000      8.0
Averages      11.666667      6.0
```

---

You can do it all together in one line using [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html). This is safer in the case where DataFrame contains other missing values that shouldn't be filled with an empty string

```
df.loc['Averages'] = df.mean(numeric_only=True).reindex(df.columns, fill_value='')
```

Note that if your DataFrame already

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but what  if I have more columns in my dataframe for that averages row that I don't want to just calculate the numeric mean of the numbers above it in that column. For instance if I waned to do a calculation on 2 averages in the same row :  like apple average | orange average  |  apple avg + orange average |  etc